# javascript script title from objective C

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview, nsstring

I am trying to call a simple javascript title from objective C.. however title always return as empty. If i change the string to a random string, title would return the random string. Meaning i am doing [webView] wrongly? whats is wrong? thankss

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application { 
    // Add code to open bundled Web site

    NSString *title = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];

    NSString *path = @"http://www.test.net";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webView loadRequest:request];

    NSLog(@"%@",title);

    // Override point for customization after application launch
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're evaluating that javascript before the webview has even loaded the page.

You should set a delegate for your UIWebView. Then the delegate should implement webViewDidFinishLoad:

When that delegate method is called, you can be sure the page has loaded and then you will be able to get the title.

Comment: ok thanks..understand the logic. will try to figure out the codes since i am very new to objective C :D